# There was an error running the tensorflow program

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

Running tensorflow `TFRecord` sample program results in the following error. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Programming questions are better suited for StackOverflow

Comment: @Maxim are you sure?

Comment: @quintumnia "Don't ask about... Programming of artificial intelligence or machine learning" - https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Maxim we're experimenting with allowing basic implementation questions (since we get so many of them;)  Nevertheless, this seems to be about an bug, which is makes it more of an Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in line 29, it should be

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={  # right
```

instead of

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Feature(feature={   # wrong!
```